# How to solve $2^{33} \mod 4725$?

Tags: congruences, chinese-remainder-theorem

Basically what I should do is:

$$2^{33} \equiv x \pmod{4725}.$$

I need to find $x$ which will give same result as $2^{33}$ when modulo $4725$.

I should find prime factors of $4725$ which are $4725 = 3^3 × 5^2 × 7^1$, and use them to calculate
\begin{align*}
2^{33} &\equiv x \pmod{3^3}\\
2^{33} &\equiv x \pmod{5^2}\\
2^{33} &\equiv x \pmod{7^1}
\end{align*}

so I could apply Chinese remainder theorem to calculate result, but I am stuck with calculating these. I don't know what to do with $2^{33}$, how to decompose it?

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Just do iterated squaring.  $2^2=4, 2^4=4^2=16,2^8=16^2\equiv 13\pmod {27}$ and so on.

Comment: Alternatively, note that $\varphi(27)=18$ so $2^{18}\equiv 1 \pmod {27}$.

Comment: ^How did you got that can you explain second step please? @lulu

Comment: @ItiShree  What second step?  You mean the second method?  Actually, I prefer the first (it's a good general approach to exponentiation).  If you want to do the second, well...I'm just using [Euler's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem).  Easy generalization of Fermat's Little Theorem.

Comment: @lulu thanks actually the first method would take some time won't it? That's why I need to know the second one. Thanks for helping.

Comment: @lulu could you write first method because I am not completely sure how to precede?

Comment: I'll post something below.

Comment: @ItiShree  I have posted both methods below.  Iterated squaring is quite rapid and very easy to automate (though I did this one by hand).

Comment: @ItiShree  I added a computation which works the entire problem $\pmod {4725}$ by iterated squaring.  For this I did use a calculator...but just to compute things like $256^2$ or $4111^2$ which really could be done by hand if you were so inclined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will compute $2^{33}\pmod {27}$ as the OP is ok with the rest of the calculation.

In what follows $\equiv $ denotes congruence $\pmod {27}$.

Method I (iterated squaring):  This works unusually well in this case because $33=32+1$ is so near a power of $2$.  We write:

$$2^2=4\implies 2^4=16\implies 2^8=16^2\equiv 13 \implies 2^{16}\equiv 13^2\equiv 7$$

$$\implies 2^{32}\equiv 7^2\equiv -5$$

It follows that $$2^{33}=2^{32}\times 2\equiv 17\pmod {27}$$

Method II (Euler):  As $\varphi(27)=18$ we have $2^{18}\equiv 1$.  Thus $2^{36}\equiv 1$ so $2^{33}\equiv 2^{-3}$.  As the inverse of $2\pmod {27}$ is clearly $14$ we see that $$2^{33}\equiv 14^3\equiv 17\pmod {27}$$

Note:  It's not especially harder to do the entire problem by iterated squaring.  Working $\pmod {4725}$ we have $$2^8=256 \implies 2^{16}\equiv 4111 \implies 2^{32}\equiv {4111}^2 \equiv 3721$$  So $$2^{33}=2^{32}\times 2 \equiv 2717\pmod {4725}$$

Answer (score 0):

Compute the orders of $2$ mod. $27$ and mod. $25$: it is  a divisor of  $\varphi(3^3)=18$ and $\varphi(5^2)=10$. So
$$2^{33}\equiv 2^{33\bmod o_{27}(2)}\mod 27,\qquad2^{33}\equiv 2^{33\bmod o_{25}(2)}\mod 25.$$